# Use of the symbolic operator $\left[e^{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\right]$ in Taylor's expansion

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

We know that Taylor's series expansion of a generic function $f(x)$, in the abscissa point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ is given by:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x_0) \tag{1}$$

$$f(x)=\left[e^{(x-x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\right]f(x_0) \tag{2}$$
Why if I expand the exponential in $(2)$ into an infinite sum and move the $(x)$ part into the sum, I'll get $(1)$ through a translation that brings the point $x_0$ to the point $x=x_0+(x-x_0)$ where 
$$e^{(x-x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-x_0)}{n!}\frac{\partial^{(n)}}{\partial x^n}, \quad ?$$

What is the connection between moment operator impulse $p_x\longrightarrow -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ along a direction,  $x$ and the $(3)$?

$$f(x)=\left[e^{(x-x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\right]f(x_0)\color{teal}{\equiv \left[e^{-\dfrac i\hbar (x-x_0)p_x}\right]} \tag{3}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? From a purely computational perspective, an answer to your question is "because if you expand the exponential in (2) into an infinite sum and move the "$(x)$" part into the sum, you'll get (1)". A rigorous mathematician will want to make sense of the exponential by explaining where exactly it is computed, but this is not too difficult (though the answer will include the words "Banach algebra" or at least "topological $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra", with the details depending on what kind of function $f$ is). Do you want a motivation?

Comment: @darijgrinberg In the meantime hello and I thank you for your comment so much. The first part of your comment is exactly what I would like to know "because if you expand the exponential in (2) into an infinite sum and move the "$(x)$" part into the sum, you'll get (1)". You are 100% authorized to edit my question also because I am not a native of English and not knowing the topic at all I do not know how to make my question clearer.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Keep in mind that I have never studied these topics and I am simply interested in the mathematical passages without  "Banach algebra" or at least "topological $\mathbb{Q}-$algebra$". It is too difficult for me with all sincerity. I'm sure you found my thanks.

Comment: Note that $$\left((x-x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^n$$ is not the same as $$(x-x_0)^n\frac{\partial^{(n)}}{\partial^{(n)}x}$$ since $x-x_0$ does not commute with $\partial/\partial x.$

Comment: Another issue with how you write (2) is that you have it operate on a constant $f(x_0)$ which does not give you what you want. The way to write it to get what you want is to write it on the form $f(t + x) = e^{t\partial_{x}}f(x)$.

Comment: I'm not going to edit the post until I know what exactly the remaining question is. As to the motivation behind $e^{t \partial/\partial x}$ acting like a shift  by $t$, there are *probably* some pictures and ideas in some people's heads that give this fact a non-computational explanation, but I don't know them well enough to give a good answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I apologize once again but I am not an expert in this field. Thank you very much for your cooperation. Keep in mind that I have only a few notes but I could better understand from your answers. Excuse me very much.

Comment: @Winther I tried to ask the best of my question. Excuse me, too.

Comment: Thank you very very much to the users that reopened my closed question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first start with a precise formulation of the equation you are referring to. For a (sufficiently nice) function $f$ we have
$$f(x+\epsilon) = e^{\epsilon\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)$$
Note that we need it to act on a function $f(x)$ and not $f(x_0)$ as you have (as this is just a constant). Also we cannot have $(x-x_0)\frac{d}{dx}$ in the exponential since $((x-x_0)\frac{d}{dx})^n \not= (x-x_0)^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$.

As to why this equation holds. First of all the definition of $e^A$ when $A$ is an operator is nothing but the usual Taylor series so $e^A \equiv 1 + A +\frac{A^2}{2} + \ldots$ so if we write out what we mean by the right hand side it becomes the series
$$(1 + \epsilon \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \ldots)f(x)\\ = f(x) + \epsilon \frac{df(x)}{dx} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}+\ldots$$
If you consider this as representing a function of just $\epsilon$ for a fixed $x$ then you will see that this is nothing but the Taylor expansion of the function $g(\epsilon) = f(x+\epsilon)$ about the point $\epsilon=0$.

The connection with the momentum operator becomes $f(x+\epsilon) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \epsilon p_x }f(x)$. This is sometimes phrased as the momentum operator being the [generator for translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)#Momentum_as_generator_of_translations) (which intuitively makes sense: momentum is what causes change in position). To understand this more deeply I suggest reading more about the mathematics of quantum mechanics which can be found in any introductory textbook. For more see e.g. [this](http://www.hep.upenn.edu/~rreece/docs/notes/derivation_of_quantum_mechanical_momentum_operator_in_position_representation.pdf) or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45067/momentum-as-generator-of-translations).