# The integral of $\sec^4(x)\tan(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral 
$$\int \sec^4(x)\tan(x)$$

Now right off the bat I see two ways of solving this.

1. Let u=$\sec(x)$

2.Use integration by parts

Now doing the first way results in the integrand looking like
$$\int u^3du=\frac{1}{4}\sec^4(x)+C $$

Which is correct but it's not the answer I'm looking for, so instead we'll do it the second way.

$$\int \sec^2(x)\cdot\sec^2(x)\tan(x)dx$$
$$\int\left(\tan^2(x)+1\right)\sec^2(x)\tan(x)dx $$
$$\int\sec^2(x)\tan^3(x)+\sec^2(x)\tan(x)dx$$
Now this is where I got stuck, because I don't know whether to continue with Pythagorean identities or to factor a term out and solve for that. Or perhaps even break the two up and create two integrals.

Comment: What answer, other than the correct answer, are you looking for? Surely you aren't looking for an *incorrect* answer ...

Comment: @clathratus The answer I am looking for is $\frac{1}{4}\tan^4(x)+\frac{1}{2}\tan^2(x)+C$

Comment: Why not $u = \cos x$ so you have $\int \frac{-\mathrm{d}u}{u^5}$?

Comment: @EricTowers That works, but I am using a review packet and the sections are integration by parts. trig integrals and arc length.

Comment: $\sec^4x=(\tan^2x+1)^2=\tan^4x+2\tan^2x+1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your integrand in the form$$\tan(x)(\tan^2(x)+1)\sec^2(x)$$ and substitute $$u=\tan(x)$$ and you will get $$\int u(u^2+1)\,du$$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but I do have one more. Why is it that the $1$ in the final integral is left as a $1$ and not made to equal $1$ in terms of $u$?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sec^2(x)=\tan^2(x)+1$$?

Comment: No, in the integral $\int u(u^2+1)du$ that $1$ is left over from the identity, but why is that so? Is it because it is a constant?

Comment: @EricBrown $u^2+1=\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$ so $u(u^2+1)du=\tan x\cdot\sec^2 x\cdot\sec^2xdx=\tan x\sec^4xdx$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

*Bioche's rules*  suggest to use the substitution $u=\tan x,\;\mathrm d u=\sec^2 x\,\mathrm dx$ to obtain a polynomial in $u$.

Comment: Hi most kind Bernard. When you have a bit of your time, can you edit my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388691/use-of-the-symbolic-operator-lefte-frac-partial-partial-x-right-in-t?noredirect=1 to have it more clear, please?. I will remove my comment when you have read my comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The form of the answer you want says you have
$$  \int \tan^3(x) + \tan(x) \,\mathrm{d}(\tan x)  \\ =  \int \left( \tan^3(x) + \tan(x) \right) \sec^2(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$$ 
in the prior step, which you do.  Let $u = \tan x$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think the solution to your question is given in the image above.